# Allowing only clean URLs in Yii

Tags: php, url, yii

I have configured the `CUrlManager` in the config/main.php to use clean URL:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'showScriptName' => FALSE,
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'rules' => require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/routes.php'),
),
```

The clean URL function works perfectly, but I would like to prevent the default `<controller>/<action>` pattern match to occur.

This is my config/route.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'books' => 'book/index'
);
```

Now people can go to the same book page by 2 different URLs:

1. http://www.mysite.com/books
2. http://www.mysite.com/book/index

I want to disable the second URL pattern. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [`useStrictParsing`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#useStrictParsing-detail) in your url manager component.